# Solving a system of non-linear equations with only one unknown

Tags: r, nonlinear-optimization

I am trying to pin down the barrier between high-skill technology and low-skill technology industries in the Task-Based model of the labor market. This takes place in the task in which the price of production is equal to each other.

[image: The definition of I]

```
    I is equal to P1 - P2 = 0    
    P1 <- (mu_L[i]^(-1)*(w_L/delta)^delta)
    P2 <- (mu_H[i]^(-1)*(w_H/alpha)^alpha)
```

It is part of a dynamic problem in which wage is dependent on I and I on wage. The relevant further equations are wage high and low: [wage high](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4mxZ.png) and [wage low](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NeKe2.png). L_L, the labour supply linked to low and high-skill is based on data and around 0.8 for L_L and 0.2 for L_H. Y is for now set on 40,000 also based on data.

```
task <- seq(0.01,1, by = 0.01)
alpha <-  0.55 
delta <- 0.83
mu_H <- task
mu_L <- 1-task
L_L <- 0.8
L_H <- 0.2
Y <- 40000
I_start <- 0.5
I <- I_start
   
w_H <- alpha * I * (Y / L_H) 
w_L <- delta*(1-I)*(Y / L_L)
```

In the definition of I, it is the task (i) in which the price of low-skill production minus the price of high-skill production is zero. the value of mu is dependent on the industry and by finding for which value of mu, the equation equals zero, one can find which industry I is. mu high is equal to i, while mu low is (1-i). i indicating the task from a uniform distribution between 0 and 1.

I have written a for loop to account for the dynamic modelling but cannot figure out how to pin down I in this, all non-linear system solvers require two unknown for two equations and I cannot figure out how to code it in such a way that it is equal to zero as a condition.

I have tried the following approaches:

using range:

```
range2 <- seq(0.01,1, by = 0.001)
range <- (1 - range2)
range[which(range^(-1)*(w_L/delta)^delta == range2^(-1)*(w_H/alpha)^alpha)]
```

The issue is that the answer lies between step 14 and 15, and as the steps are too large there is no exact match found. Also not when I increase the steps to 1e-8, at some point I get an error that there are too many steps. If I could at a tolerance level here that might be the solution, however, I dont know how I can do that. I tried it like this:

```
r <- range^(-1)*(w_L/delta)^delta - range2^(-1)*(w_H/alpha)^alpha
rr <- ifelse(r<0.01, print(TRUE), print(FALSE))
data.r <- data.frame(r, rr)
length(unique(data.r$rr))
```

but the tolerance might be too small, at the same time, the difference must be between 0 and 1, as the mu is limited between 0 and 1. So I feel that a tolerance of 0.01 is not asking too much. In the theory that should work.

I tried the nleqslv package but it gives me answers outside of the range [0,1].

```
dslnex <- function(x) {
  y <- numeric(2)
  y[1] <- (x[1]^(-1)*(w_L/delta)^delta)
  y[2] <- (x[2]^(-1)*(w_H/alpha)^alpha)
  y 
}
xstart=c(0.5, 0.5)
nleqslv(xstart, dslnex, control = list())
```

I am hoping to find for which value of mu such that the two equations for price are equal to each other so I can pin down the task (i) in which this is.

Comment: I'm confused.  The way you've written this `(w_L/delta)^delta` is a constant (let's say `c1`), as is `(w_H/alpha)^alpha)` (`c2`).  You seem to be asking to solve the equation `c1/range == c2/range`, which generically doesn't have a solution  (the two curves don't cross) ...

Comment: It is true that these are constants in this single solve, the difference should be in the range, with one going from 0-1 and the other from 1-0. I have changed the code above to capture this. It was my mistake to make the two ranges the same and indeed they would not cross.

Edit: It did now find the range in which it crosses and the tolerance of 0.01 is small enough to find a solution. Going to try from here to figure out what that means for my i

Comment: Edit: It did now find the range in which it crosses and the tolerance of 0.01 is small enough to find a solution. It would still be great to find the absolute number where they converge, but this already helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `uniroot()` for this:

```r
f <- function(x) {
   (1/x)*(w_L/delta)^delta - (1/(1-x))*(w_H/alpha)^alpha
}
uniroot(f, c(1e-2, 1))
```

Solution:

```
$root
[1] 0.888271

$f.root
[1] -1.03622

$iter
[1] 9

$init.it
[1] NA

$estim.prec
[1] 6.103516e-05
```

For more precision (if you need it) you can reduce the tolerance: `uniroot(f, c(1e-2, 1), tol = 1e-8)` gives a root at 0.8882506

Comment: Thank you! This works in one line and is perfect! I tried uniroot before but could not figure it out. I can now incorporate it into my loop.